# In JPA @QueryHint for using specific index

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to use jpa queryhint to force query for using specific index like

```
@QueryHints(value = {@QueryHint(name = "INDEX", value = "CWQ_KEY_IDX")})
```

Query will be:

```
select /*+ INDEX(CWQ_KEY_IDX) */ * from <table>
```

but I am getting warning in log file :

> hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl - HHH000121: Ignoring unrecognized query hint [INDEX]

After googling I got this format

```
@QueryHint(name=QueryHints.HINT, value="/*+ index(scott.emp ix_emp) * /");
```

But `QueryHints` class in current version doesn't contain `HINT` instance variable.

any thought what I am doing wrong here??

Comment: [QueryHints.HINT](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.4/org/eclipse/persistence/config/QueryHints.html#HINT) is EclipseLink extension and you are using Hibernate.

Comment: Yes, I know. But how we will do it in hibernate?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-embed-oracle-hints-in-hibernate-query/) one?